# Promise is always undefined when resolving for async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm doing a database query in an `async` function, then calling it from another file with a `promise`. But the result of the `promise` is always `undefined`.

My db function:

```
async function findSomething(id) {
   var query = "my_query";
   connection.query(query);
};
```

This is how I'm calling it from another file:

```
DbUtil.findSomething(1).then(function(result, error) {
   if(!error) {
    console.log("the result " + result);
  }
});
```

The result is always `undefined`.

Note that the calling function, `DbUtil.findSomething` is called from another file. I do not want to chain it inside the `findSomething()` function.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've rolled your question back because your edit turned it into a completely different question. How you get your own async function to return a value (which is what you asked about) and how you use the `connection.query` API (or how you promisify a function which accepts a callback instead of returning a promise) are very different questions and should be asked as seperate questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `return` statement.

Any function without one returns `undefined`.

Since `findSomething` is as `async` function, the return value is used to resolve the promise it returns.

```
async function findSomething(id) {
  var query = "my_query";
  return connection.query(query);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I get a `[object Object]` in `DbUtil.findSomething`. How do I get the results from it?

Comment: @Eddy — Look at the documentation for connection.query. Don't just convert the object to a string.